How to dynamically add DOM elements with Blazor?
I have a chat-like Blazor application that I need to continuously add DOM elements to:
<EditForm model="this" OnValidSubmit="@Query">
    <div id="qrContainer">
        <div>
            <input type="text" @ref="queryElement" @bind="query" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="output" @bind="response"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
@code {
    private String query { get; set; } = null;
    private String response { get; set; }
    private ElementReference queryElement;

    private async Task Query(){
        // ...
            var responseString = await responseService.getResponseAsync(query);
            // Need to add DOM element to "output" here.
        // ...
    }
}

From what I understand, JSInterop is not the preferred way to do this. So, how do I add new DOM elements the "Blazor" way?

I believe your approaching this from the wrong direction.  You see the need to add the new responseString into the DOM to update the display.  What you actually do is let the component [in this case the page] handle the DOM updates based on the component and data state.
Here's a very simplistic example based on your code snippet.
A record, a Singleton service to hold the data and an event to notify registered handlers of a change.
public record Comment(DateTime TimeStamp, string Value);

public class ChatRoom
{
    public event EventHandler? ItemsChanged;
    private readonly List<Comment> _items = new();

    public IEnumerable<Comment> Items => _items.OrderByDescending(item => item.TimeStamp);


    public void PostComment(object? sender, string comment)
    {
        _items.Add(new(DateTime.Now, comment));
        this.ItemsChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

Registered in DI:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ChatRoom>();

And the Chat page - in this case Home:
@page "/"
@inject ChatRoom ChatRoom
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Chat world!</h1>
<textarea class="form-control" @bind=_currentComment @bind:event="oninput" />

<div class="text-end m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="@_noComment" @onclick="AddComment">Add Comment</button>
</div>

@foreach (var item in ChatRoom.Items)
{
    <div @key="item" class="bg-light m-2 p-2 border border-1 rounded-3">@item.Value</div>
}

@code {
    private string? _currentComment;
    private bool _noComment => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_currentComment);
    private object _identity = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.ChatRoom.ItemsChanged += this.OnItemsChanged;

    private void AddComment()
    {
        if (_currentComment is not null)
            ChatRoom.PostComment(_identity, _currentComment);

        _currentComment = null;
    }

    public void OnItemsChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If I raised the event then I don't need to render again.
        if (sender != _identity)
            this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => this.ChatRoom.ItemsChanged -= this.OnItemsChanged;
}

AddComment is a called from a UI event [the button click], so the UI event handler invoking AddComment calls StateHasChanged on completion.  At this point the Chat Items have been updated, so the current list [including the item you've added] is displayed.
Two browser windows interacting:

